# get real product version in c#

Tags: c#, version

This may seem fairly straight forward, however, the typical methods to get the version only grab the version info which needs to be manually set, and not the build versions from publish.

This results in (if I never go into the properties and change the value deep inside project settings), the version always returning 1.0.0.0.  In fact, this is also the version that always shows up when I right click any compiled .NET exe from inside any of the publish folders. For example :

`/publish/1.0.0.2/foo.exe`

The properties show `1.0.0.0`, even though that is build `1.0.0.2`.

I am willing to accept a solution that will do either of the following :

1. Automatically set the actual file version to the current version on publish.
2. Obtain the actual version (not 1.0.0.0) using c#.

Not looking for a hack to add my own versioning system. I would like to use the mechanisms that are built in (and were working PERFECTLY in predecessors to .NET).

For added clarification, it seems the auto-versioning is garbage in .NET, and instead of using the Publish version, it is using the versions from inside

Properties > Application > [Assembly Information]
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this could be your solution:

```
using System.Reflection;

....

string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
FileVersionInfo versioninfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);

return fvi.FileVersion; // type: string
```

This piece of code returns the version of an assembly as set inside the manifest-file. It also works for retrieving the assembly version of a nativ application/library

---

**Edit:** As [adv12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771817/adv12) wrote previously, this would be my updated solution:

```
using System.Deployment;

...

if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(4));
```

Comment: This still only returns 1.0.0.0 .  Also, this information that the above method returns, is accessible from the regular version methods.  My problem, is I wish to use the build version from Properties>Publish Version .....  but all that is ever on the executable is Properties>Application>Assembly Information .  Give me a minute to update the screenshot.

Comment: @SanuelJackson: Ok, Sir. I will continue my search. I am sorry that I missunderstood your question and I will update my response as soon as I find the correct solution.

Comment: Not a problem.  I am going to try the other solution posted by adv12.

Comment: After the error (as commented on adv's solution), and a bit of digging, it appears that method is only available for ClickOnce applications --- terribad.  I am not using ClickOnce.  Traditional installed applications only, so straight exe, not an exe stashed in some obscure path after streaming it.  :)

Comment: @SanuelJackson: I'm sorry to hear that, Sir. So, I assume that this thread is closed, as there is no solution for your problem, is there?

Comment: @SanuelJackson: Yes, I know what you mean, I have sometime this feeling too......

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using something like:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

...which will (I think) get the version number from attributes typically contained in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
```

To get the information from your build, use:

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
```

...but note that the latter will throw an exception when the application is not deployed, as when you're debugging within Visual Studio.  So you probably want a try/catch around the latter that falls back to the former.

Comment: Testing this.  And of course deploy only, I can always just check if inside the IDE or not :) .  Was really hoping this worked, but when running the compiled exe, I get this message `System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Application identity is not set.
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.get_CurrentDeployment()`